# Angular Material Progress spinner and Progress bar does'nt show

Tags: angular, progress-bar, angular-material, spinner, transparent

I'm working on Angular 4. And I made a new project with :

```
ng new test-app
```

Then I ran :

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
ng g c first
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FirstComponent } from './first/first.component';

import { MatProgressBarModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**first.component.html**

```html
<p>
  first works!
</p>


<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>

<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="40"></mat-progress-bar>
```

[Result here in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wXK9.png)

[image: Result with the inspector browser]

In the inspector the spinner looks like to be working. (same things for the progress bar)
But without the inspector I can not see anything.

I tried to change color in css, the background seems to works but the color doesn't change anything.
Whatever I tried, I can not see my spinner or my progress-bar.

I tried ever on Mozilla / Chrome / IE11, same problems.

Does anyone have an idea ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to import a theme in your `styles.css`, e.g. add this line to the top of the file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Since some components depend on the `BrowserAnimationsModule`, you should always import it for animations to work.

For more detailed information about the required setup, checkout the [setup guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

Override css in style.scss in angular:

```
.mat-progress-spinner.mat-progress-spinner-indeterminate- 
animation[mode=indeterminate] {
    animation: mat-progress-spinner-linear-rotate 2s linear infinite !important;
}

.mat-progress-spinner.mat-progress-spinner-indeterminate- 
animation[mode=indeterminate] circle {
    transition-property: stroke !important;
    animation-duration: 4s !important;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.35,0,.25,1) !important;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in you styles.css

```
.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
     stroke: blue; 
}
```